# Discord.js @everyone / @here issues with message

Tags: arguments, discord.js, args

I have the code here for my embed announce feature, if a role is mentioned then it sends that role mention to the channel and then sends the rest of the message in an embed, i also have a variation for user mentions. How do i adapt this to do the same for @everyone & @here? they dont have ID's like roles. Either that or i cant find the ID of @everyone & @here. typing @everyone results in @everyone being returned, not an ID

```
if (args[1].startsWith('<@&') && args[1].endsWith('>')) {
                            message.channel.send(args[1])
                            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                                .setTitle(`${(args.slice(2).join(" "))}`)
                                .setColor(0x320b52)
                                .setTimestamp()
                                .setFooter('Requested by ' + message.author.tag)
                            message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, `@everyone` and `@here` do not have IDs. Simply check whether either of them matches `args[1]`.